# How do I set the default Scala version?

Tags: sbt, version

One way is to set up the system `PATH` to appropriate `scala/bin` variable so that scala interpreter will work. I am asking about `sbt`.

As I understand, it sets the Scala version to the one it was build for. That is, I have installed scala 2.11 but, when I run `sbt` -> `console`, I see that scala 2.10 was started. I know that I can change this version using [`scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Howto/scala.html). But, this works only for the current project. How do I make it a default option or I should not?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `sbtopts` file which should be located in the `conf` directory of sbt installation directory. (This is platform dependent)

```
# Scala version (default: latest release)
#
-scala-home <path>
```

This option is normally uncommented, but default does not seem to be the latest release in your case.

The specification of `scalaVersion := "2.11.8` is only relevant for the project where it is specified and no global setting.